# Como alterar o tipo de iphone na visualização do storyboard ?

Tags: swift

**Segue imagem abaixo,** o que acontece é o seguinte, em baixo onde aparece device, tem alguns tipos de tablet e smartphones, porém não aparece todos os tipos, eu preciso mudar para Iphone 7, como fazer isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

No storyboard não é preciso pois a proporção do 7 e o 8 são as mesmas, na parte superior esquerda é possível variar entre qualquer dispositivo para se fazer um *build* e testar no simulador